# Gradle Sync not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I replaced my Android Studio with the Latest one and then I am not able to sync the project and I am getting this error again and again...

org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/JavaVersion;)V

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2017-03-09 10:09:15,334 [1083233]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'FreeDeemer' failed: org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/gradle/api/JavaVersion;)V

Comment: which java version are you currently using?

Comment: Hi! I am using "java version "1.8.0_121"

Comment: Dont know what the problem was but when I copied a whole new Android studio it solved my problem.

Comment: that's good but identify what is the problem behind it . now check your java version. JDK 1.8 versions having issues with android studio that's by i recommend you to use  JDk 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Java version 1.8 and above are not fully supportable for android studio so use  java JDK 1.7, it will work fine. thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to start Android Studio with Java 7 nor does it allow to configure it for the project.